# Git clone Error for Poky from Yocto

Tags: git, sockets, proxy, ubuntu-14.04, yocto

My company uses a proxy script for internet access. My host is Windows and I use VirtualBox to run Ubuntu 14.04. I want use GIT to download a poky file from yocto, using code:

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
```

I followed this link: [Working Behind a Network Proxy](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Working_Behind_a_Network_Proxy) and also set the proxy for Firefox and apt. I got the error like this:

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky

Cloning into 'poky'...

2017/08/31 11:42:40 socat[4846] E read(): EOF during read of socks reply, peer might not be a socks4 server

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In my `~/.bashrc`, I added my proxy like this:

```
export http_proxy='*http://usrname:password@myproxy.mycompany.de:8080/wpad.dat*'
export ALL_PROXY='socks://usrname:password@myproxy.mycompany.de:8080/wpad.dat'
export GIT_PROXY_COMMAND="oe-git-proxy"
export NO_PROXY=$no_proxy
```

Should I use another way to setup my password and username? Should I use `http` instead of `socks` in my `ALL_PROXY` export?

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: and i followed Working Behind a Network Proxy to set proxy for wget, i got the error,ERROR 407: Proxy Authorization Required. In ~/.wgetrc i have this code:use_proxy = on ,http_proxy =http://usrname:password@myproxy.mycompany.de:8080/wpad.dat

Comment: Does network connection work with other programs? E.g. `curl google.com` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your company might use NTLM authentification which is not supported by the protocol in your exports in `~/.bashrc`.

You need another other proxy on localhost which undertakes your authentification.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/files/cntlm/cntlm%200.92.3/

CNTLM can do this. Install `cntlm_0.92.3_amd64.deb` with the command

```
sudo dpkg -i cntlm_0.92.3_amd64.deb
```

Configure the settings in the file `/etc/cntlm.conf`:

```
Username <username>
Domain <domain>
Password <password>
Proxy <company-proxy>
Listen 3128  # should be default
NoProxy  localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.* # should be default
```

Then restart CNTLM service with `sudo service cntlm restart`.

As environment variables for your proxy you now need: `http://127.0.0.1:3128`:

```
export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128"
```

Comment: Test this first with `wget google.com` or `curl google.com` or something since git might require another configuration

Comment: Thank you h0ch5tr4355, i tried the wget google.com , i get Error 407,Proxy Authorization Required.(i have seted wget proxy). and with curl www.google.com, i get: ....,The document has moved,.......

Comment: and i tried this (wget http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/scripts/oe-git-proxy), i get the error (Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authorization Required). What interesting is, if i do (wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-5/v5.5.23/bin/apache-tomcat-5.5.23.zip), i can download the zip-file!

Comment: i tried to use cntlm, it returns:/home/gigi/bin/connect: not found,Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: So in one example wget works and in the other it doesn't?

Comment: hallo h0ch5tr4355, as you said,wegt works with archive.apache.org but not yoctor.org. i wonder if Firewall blocks the link. But i can visit the site with browser.

Comment: The `*` in your http_proxy variable. What do they mean?

Comment: i wanted to make the text of link as a italic format, and * changes text to italic.  in my config file there is no * . :D I set the cntlm, and i have the error : Proxy request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying, when i wget www.google.com. had you problem like that?

Comment: I doubt that you need CNTLM when wget works without it in some cases.  It does work without CNTLM, doesnt it?

Comment: without CNTLM i can wget the file (http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-5/v5.5.23/bin/apache-tomcat-5.5.23.zip), but not the file (http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/scripts/oe-git-proxy). i install cntlm now, and it has error (Proxy request sent, awaiting response... No data received. Retrying), when i wget (http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-5/v5.5.23/bin/apache-tomcat-5.5.23.zip)

Comment: i use VM in Windows, should i also install cntlm for windows?